# Encode part of URL in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

What is the proper way to encode a URL in Razor? My attempt below isn't changing the spaces into `%20`.

`survey.Name` is the variable passed to the controller

```
<a href="~/Survey/Take/@Uri.EscapeDataString(survey.Name)">@survey.Name</a>
```

Comment: What if you use `@Html.Encode(survey.Name)`

Comment: @Hackerman still doesn't encode it.

Comment: @HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(survey.Name)

Comment: @NagarajRaveendran nope still shows up with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Url.Encode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Encode);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(survey.Name, "Take", "Survey", new { name = Url.Encode(survey.Name) }, new { })
```

As a side note, the link works without encoding the space. You would need to encode it when the link will be used outside your app, such as in an email.

Comment: So even when i click and hover over the link it will still show the spaces as which it is doing now because it's local and not external?

Comment: @Tsukasa mine shows the spaces encoded when using Url.Encode(). My side note just meant that the link would still work with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

[HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode(v=vs.110).aspx) should work fine in your case. Tried and tested!

[Here's a working fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EgOMnN)

```
<a href="~/Survey/Take/@HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(survey.Name)">@survey.Name</a>
```

**Update:** (Thanks @Sam Rueby)

> Do not use; intended only for browser compatibility. Use UrlEncode.

Comment: Description for this method states "Do not use; intended only for browser compatibility. Use UrlEncode".

Comment: Thanks.@SamRueby. Updated and added to answer. I havent seen that before, may the documentation was updated.

Comment: Sadly HttpUtility.UrlEncode still encodes spaces as +, and the now defunct UrlPathEncode doesn't encode #